# How to stream videos from URL in Android?

Tags: android, video-streaming, web-scraping, jsoup

I'm using JSoup for scraping a website that includes embedded videos. Not every video is hosted in YouTube, they are hosted in different websites. How can I display those videos in my app?

I have not tried anything because I have no idea if it is even possible.

It would be fine if I can at least display a thumb image and when the user click on it, it would open the browser or the default video app.

Update: http://www.viddler.com this is where the videos are hosted. I'm doing some research to see if some how I can stream the videos to my app. But this is my first time trying something like this some everything looks a bit complicated.

Comment: Depending on the provider of the videos, there might be an API for it which allows you to play videos. As for the thumbnail, I am unsure. You might be able to parse the video link with Jsoup and display that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This entirely depends on the video content provider. You can write logic to look at the urls determine the provider and get additional information like thumbnail and even video playback based on whether the provider provides a method to do so. This isn't specific to Android if you really think about it.